# HTML5 file download attribute IOS chrome

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, download

Seems that currently using download attribute to download a file on IOS chrome is not working:

```
<a href="01.mp3" download>Download Receipt</a>
```

It works on Safari, but on chrome it just opens in new window and plays, instead of downloading it.

It works on Android as well. Is there a known fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hi perhaps you can try this

```
<a href="01.mp3" download="01.mp3">
```

Comment: I have just tried, but its the same result.